# kedro pyspark starter cannot load spark.SparkDataset

Tags: kedro

The kedro starter project immediately fails to recognize the spark dataset

```
kedro new --starter=spaceflights-pyspark-viz
cd projectpath
pip install -r requirements.txt
kedro ipython
Class 'spark.SparkDataset' not found, is this a typo?
```

Tested with kedro 0.19.1 and .2

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you explicitly install `pip kedro-datasets[spark.SparkDataset]` does it work? This should be part of the `requirements.txt`

Comment: hi, yes I also have it installed, but no, still the same issue

Comment: Hiya - can you confirm it's on the same python environment. Inspecting your `sys.path` is the easiest way to confirm this.

Comment: `import sys ; sys.path` doesn't show anything related to `kedro-datasets` or `spark.SparkDataset`, just the regular paths to `site-packages`, `ipython`, `lib`, and so on. what should I expect?

Comment: That suggests your iPython environment is referencing the wrong venv